# Chrome bug: lose space between inline elements inside display:table

Tags: css, google-chrome

It seems there is a bug in Chrome: it removes the white space which is normally between the inline elements when these are inside a parent with `display:table` style.

```html
<div style="display:table;">
  <span>text1</span> <span>text2</span> 
  <span>text3</span>
</div>
```

Edge/Firefox display this space without problem. Any ideas about workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-breaking space HTML character entity `&nbsp;`.

```
<div style="display:table;">
  <span>text1</span>&nbsp;<span>text2</span>
</div>
```

Which will get you space between items on all browsers.